# Pandas with lru_cache how to convert 'Series' objects to unmutable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, caching

I know there are some similar question, but they all have not been solved.

I'm using python lru_cache in pandas project:

```
from functools import lru_cache
for df_ia in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=n,iterator=True, low_memory=False):

    @lru_cache(maxsize = None)
    def myfunc(df_ia):
        print('my logic here')
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I checked some answers in stack overfollow ,I know  the error comes about because I passed a tuple of Series rather than a tuple of column names/strings, but no answer is about how to solve this issue when read from a csv.

Any friend can help?

Comment: If the series in question only have hashable indices (e.g. int) and values (e.g. numbers), and the return of the function in question only depends on the series index and values, then you could define a little wrapper class with a simple `__eq__` and `__hash__` function that stores the series in an attribute.

Comment: @Timus Thank you very much for your reply,can you give me an example ?thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just as an illustration of my comment. This

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def func(ser):
    return ser.sum()

ser = pd.Series(range(10))
func(ser)
```

doesn't work, as you have outlined:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

If you do wrap the series into a hashable class, for example like

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, ser):
        self.ser = ser
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.ser.equals(other.ser)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((tuple(self.ser.index), tuple(self.ser.values)))
```

and modify the function accordingly

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def func(wrapped_ser):
    ser = wrapped_ser.ser
    return ser.sum()
```

and then do

```
func(Wrapper(pd.Series(range(10))))
print(func.cache_info())
func(Wrapper(pd.Series(range(10))))
print(func.cache_info())
```

you'll get

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=None, currsize=1)
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=None, currsize=1)
```

But I'm not sure if that's suitable for your use case. Might well be that you must be more careful with the wrapping.

EDIT: Some additional words of caution: Mutable objects are by default *not* hashable, since the hash of an object shouldn't change over its lifetime. Series are obviously mutable. So if your function does change the underlying series, this is *not* a good idea. As long as the function just calculates some result based on the data in the series this might work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your long answer, really appreciate it.I have a more specific question here,can you help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712146/pandas-pd-apply-function-work-with-python-caches-cannot-be-hashed